# deleting vs. destroying a session in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I don't understand the difference.  I've been following Michael Hartl's Rails tutorial and in my routes file I have the following:

```
  resources :sessions, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]

  match '/signin', to: "sessions#new"
  match '/signout', to: "sessions#destroy", via: :delete
```

the site works with and without the `via: :delete`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `via` option constraints the route to that HTTP verb. In this case, probably, the request is being made using the `DELETE` verb, so constraining this or not doesn't make any difference.

Note that `destroy` is the name of the action, `delete` is referencing the HTTP verb.

Comment: So when would the *destroy* action NOT call the *delete* verb?

Comment: @tir38 It's the other way, the delete verb is commonly associated with a destroy action.

Comment: ok, so the verb calls the action. But when would *delete* NOT call *destroy*?

Comment: @tir38 that would depend on how you specify the routes. The `resources` method defines a destroy action associated with a delete verb. You can always define the routes the way you want.